# How can I add condition to call vue component if local storage javascript exist in view blade laravel?

Tags: javascript, laravel-5.3, vuejs2, laravel-blade, vue-component

My view blade laravel like this :

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li>
        ...
    </li>
    // if exist local storage run this component
    <notification-view></notification-view>
</ul>
```

I want to add condition if local storage exist, it will run the component vue

I have main.js and I have code to check local storage exist or no like this :

```
if (localStorage.getItem("storedData") !== null) {
   ...
}
```

How can I add the condition on the view blade?

**Update**

My notification vie component like this :

```
<template>
    <li> 
        ...
    </li>
</template>
<script>
    export default{
        ...
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, this question has nothing to do with Laravel. It is just Vue.

You can bind the local storage data to view the property and directly use `v-if` directive to decide whether to show the component or not.

Simply use `localStorage.setItem()` to set a property, and then user `localStorage.getItem()` to fetch the property and bind it.

Check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/6wz9ynat/) for a fiddle.

You can simply use the `v-if` directive on the

`<notification-view v-if="someProperty"></notification-view>`

to display or hide the component.

Comment: This : `<notification-view v-if="someProperty"></notification-view>`. Do you mean some property is class? The component is in the laravel blade view

Comment: `someProperty` can be a data poperty or a vue computed method.

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot